# php foreach print whole line not only match

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

```
$lines = file('vairinfo.txt');
$eilutes;

for($u = 0; $u < count($vairmas) ; $u++){
    $eilutes = " ";
    $number = 0;
    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
    {
        if (strpos($line,$vairmas[$u])!== FALSE){
            $number++;
            $eilutes = $line . " ";
            if($number == 2){
                echo $eilutes;
```

Basically, i'm trying to print whole line if match is correct. But in mine code it only prints last match not all matches

Comment: You're re-setting `$eilutes = $line . " ";` whenever there's a match. Try `$eilutes .= $line . " ";` instead.

Comment: Why is `if($number == 2){` there? Why does `$number` need to be `2`?

Comment: i need to print line if there are 2 or more matches

Comment: if you need 2 or more matches if($number >= 2) is more likely to be correct

Comment: then mark my answer below as correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need 2 or more matches if($number >= 2) is more likely to be correct.